# Preview full link in Pandas data frame

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, pandas

Using Pandas I receive the following data frame:

```
                             _links                         code  \
0   {u'players': {u'href': u'http://api.football-d...       MUFC
```

For testing purposes; is there a way to view the full links, in 'column' `_links`, when `printing` the data frame?

For example, I'd like the output to appear as followed:

```
                                    _links                                         code  \
0   {u'players': {u'href': u'href":"http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/66       MUFC
```

Comment: Need to set this via it's options attribute - `pd.set_option('max_colwidth', some_large_number)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need set `max_colwidth`, see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#frequently-used-options):

```
#if need temporary set option
with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', 100):
    print (df)
                                                                      _link  \
0  {u'players': {u'href': u'href':'http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/66   

   code  
0  MUFC
```

If need change default value ([50](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#available-options)):

```
 pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 100)
```